# Which plugins are available for jenkins to change the test config from jenkins UI interface?

Tags: testng, jenkins

I have integrated my testNG based selenium test framework with jenkins. Currently user have to open the code and enable/disable the test cases in testNG.xml file.

Now I want an interface on Jenkins page so that the user will be able to specify which test he want to run.

Is there any plugin available to handle this or any other way through which we can handle this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would use the standard parameters option in a jenkins build.  If my testng.xml file has been organized with groups, I can use a string parameter to pass in groups of test to run or exclude.  Additionally, I could use the choice parameter and provide all the valid command line options to execute my test suite.